# Is not having a shaatnez label considered מראית עין‎?

Tags: halacha, marit-ayin, shaatnez

In a personal encounter with a fellow Jew, they pointed out that I did not have a 'shaatnez label' in my suit. Although it is a prevalent custom for shaatnez checkers to sew their label into a checked item I didn't like its appearance and so removed it.

Due to the prevalence of shaatnez labels, is it indeed considered מראית עין‎ to remove such a label?

Comment: That's already going too far

Comment: @sam I agree, but experiencing this a couple of times made me wonder the extent of  מראית עין for this case

Comment: That's almost like saying that if a person "tucks" his tzitzit inside (a legitimate practice), an onlooker might think he's not wearing them, when of course he is wearing them.

Comment: there is no requirement to even have your suit checked by a "shatnez checker" lol

Answer (score 5):

Yad Malachi states in the name of the pri chadash, Yorah De'ah siman 87 sk 7 that we don't make up new concerns of maris ayin beyond what is in the Gemara.

Answer (score 4):

Since the label is sewn into the inside of the suit, how would anyone know that it is not there? I normally staple it into the inside of the suit so that I will remember that I have had it checked. If it is not there, you might get it confused with a different suit that you need to check.

Marit Ayin is a matter of how something appears to people walking by and seeing it. An example was the necessity to put the box of nondairy creamer with the pareve marking on the table when they first came out. Now that they are well known, that is no longer required by the hecsherim at the caterers that I have seen.

Thus, the shatnez label would not be a case of marit ayin because it is something that you would check for yourself and not need the certificate. For example, it is only at a catered affair that the cateres put out a sign saying what the hashgacha is or restaurants put up a hechser sign. You would not do that in your home.

In fact the Baltimore Star-K gives out a shatnez label but does not sew it into the suit. If you want it (for your own reasons) fine. If not, you do not need to put it in. As I said above, I just do it so that I will remember when I buy a new suit.

Comment: There is one big diff,by the case of the non dairy creamer one might come to think one is doing an issue 100 %,by not having a shatnez label it is an additional safek 1)that the suit was checked already maybe and 2) even if not checked maybe its not a miut hamatzoi and even if it is it is still a safek whether it has shatnez

Comment: @sam That is part of the point. It is also like timers on the lights when they first came out. All of these cases are obvious things visible to others which is **not** the case by the shatnez labels. I am just pointing out that putting it in is a matter of practicality and not necessity. I will add to make it clearer.

Comment: People weren't nosy. But upon taking off my jacket someone didn't see it in my suit in the normal place. Hence the question.

Comment: @bondonk If you are not offended, you can answer "I prefer not to have it there" or you can say "why do you ask?" or you can act offended. It depends on you and who the person is.

Answer (score 3):

I have, several times, called a *shaatnez* lab (the so-called "*Mikdash Melech*" one in [Midwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midwood,_Brooklyn), though I think it no longer has any connection with [*Mikdash Melech*](http://www.mikdashmelech.net/)), asked about a certain article of clothing whether it has *shaatnez*, and was told that there is a *chazaka* (reliable status quo, in this case based on the manufacturer and place of origin) that it does not and that I could wear it. Obviously, there's no tag sewn into those articles of clothing, but I find it hard to believe that any *mar'is ayin* attaches. (Moreover, the *shaatnez* lab's telling me I could wear the clothing without sending me a tag implies that it, too, thinks there's no problem.)

Comment: E.g.: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/49265

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe (OC II:40) Defines maras ayin as the prohibition of doing something that appears to be forbidden when it will influence others to commit an act which is a sin.

Aside from this definition Maras ayin are specific things which the rabbis said are maras ayin and not simply being nosy and assuming that someone is doing something wrong. If just observing any action at all there could be no end to the assumptions of what is or isn't maras ayin. This is why it's important to understand what the prohibition is and how would this specific action lead others to do something prohibited not just an assumption about somebody's personal behavior.