# Is there a concern of Shaatnez with New Era hats?

Tags: halacha, shaatnez, modern-times

According to this link http://shatnez.n3.net

> Caps/Hats: Requires testing when fabric is wool, tweed, or linen-look. Genuine wool "Kangol" caps do not need testing.

The only other link I could find that was related was [on the Yeshiva world](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/kashrus-corner/98059/shatnez-laboratory-finds-shatnez-in-baseball-cap.html).

[New Era](http://shop.neweracap.com/) hats are very popular hats so I figured I would ask on here if anyone has any experience with them. I know shatnez can be a tricky thing and something that normally doesn't have it still potentially could. But has anyone had any of their wool hats tested for shatnez? They are probably the most popular brand of fitted hats in the United States. Some of the official MLB hats are 100% polyester so I am guessing one wouldn't have to have those tested. But it seems like over half of New Era's hats are 100% wool and I would like to know if rabbis or organizations had something to say about New Era hats, specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Rabbi Harari of the Midwood Shatnez Laboratory these hats are a wool poly blend made in China with no fear of linen being used. They are fine to wear.

Comment: I noticed some of the New Era hats I recently purchased are made in Vietnam and not China...is that still safe to wear?

Comment: I can try to contact him personally if you like. Or you can call the Shatnez lab yourself and either speak to him or any of the other testers there. This is the number of the Shatnez lab 1 718-382-5689.

Comment: Hi user6591 I called that number today but it went to an answering machine. If you could you relay him the question about the Vietnam made New Eras would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. I didn't speak to Rabbi Harrari but I spoke to a coworker of his in the shatnez lab, Rabbi Dubin. He said he is not worried and he assumes it is fine.

Comment: I just purchased another wool hat from new era and this one says made in Bangladesh.

Comment: When I spoke to Rabbi Dubin that time he didn't seem concerned what the country of origin was.